# Does SQLite .NET Accept interfaces in the CreateTable Method

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics, interface, create-table

At the moment I am trying to create a generic class to create a table that can either take a class or an interface as T. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class MobileDataBase<T> where T : new()
{
    SQLiteConnection database;

    public MobileDataBase()
    {
        database.CreateTable<T>();
    }
}
```

This works fine when I feed a class into it like so:

```
MobileDataBase<MyClass> database = new MobileDataBase<MyClass>();
```

But gives me the error:

> Must be non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in
>   order to use it as parameter T in the generic type or method

if I give it the arguments

```
MobileDataBase<IMyInterface> database = new MobileDataBase<IMyInterface>();
```

The reason I use an interface is because I have two objects that inherit this interface and I would like to store their information in the same table rather than two seperate ones...

I also want to use the generic class `MobileDataBase` for other classes that do not inherit from  `IMyInterface` therefore:

```
public class MobileDataBase<T> where T : IMyInterface
```

is not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a solution to this problem:

So `MyClass : IMyInterface` but the problem comes when I try to feed the interface `IMyInterface` into my generic method which in turn calls `CreateTable<T>()`

So This is what I did. I created a base class called `MyBaseClass` And implemented that instead of the interface..

```
MyClass : MyBaseClass
```

Now I can pass `MyBaseClass` into the generic method no problem. If you still want to use the interface you can make MyBaseClass implenet the Interface like so:

```
MyBaseClass : IMyInterface
```

in addition to this when using the

```
database.Insert(object, type)
```

use it like

```
database.Insert(MyClass,typeof(MyBaseClass)
```